# Taking values from multiple arraylist in order

Tags: java, database, arraylist

I have 4 array list

```
ArrayList<String[]> split_url = new ArrayList<String[]>();
ArrayList<String> mediaID = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> productID = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> clusResult = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and each arraylist contains some values. i want to take first value from each arralist and save that into one row in database then take second values from each database and save that to next row and so on.... how can i do that ?

Comment: Please do not post such generic questions. First try out something and post a question with your approach so that someone over here could refine it or suggest changes.

Comment: What have you tried? You can simply iterate over the largest ArrayList and get the values in order. Everything else is just too broad.

Comment: this is for a similar image implimentation and there is a lot functions inside that which is a little complicated.. so i was unable to show all here.  
I will explain something simply. i want to take first data from split URL take first data from  clustResult and media id and produst ID. but if the clusResult has multiple values seperated by (,) then i want same clusResult data with next values of split_url, mediaid and productid. if there is 2 (,) then it repeat for the next 2 rows. so i want to get the count of how many values seperated by (,) in clusResult arraylist. sory dint mentond befor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) first initialize all the array lists with zeros upto a certain length l.

2) add some values to each array list.

3) run the a loop like this,

```
for(int x=0;x<l;x++)
{
   String a=split_url(x);
   String b=mediaId(x);
   String c=productId(x);
   String d=clusResult(x);
   // now store a,b,c,d as a record in your database;
}
```

Comment: i want to take first data from split URL take first data from  clustResult and media id and produst ID. but if the clusResult has multiple values seperated by (,) then i want same clusResult data with next values of split_url, mediaid and productid. if there is 2 (,) then it repeat for the next 2 rows. so i want to get the count of how many values seperated by (,) in clusResult arraylist. sory dint mentond before...

Comment: you can get the count of values seperated by (,) in clusResult, by applying the split(",") method of String class, like this:  String s[]=clusResult(x).splt(","); int count=s.length;